# Can't lock screen on Genymotion devices API 21 and above

Tags: android, adb, genymotion, lockscreen

I'm trying lock screen by using appium `driver.lockscreen` or straight by using **adb command** , non of them has been working on devices with API 21 and above, 
it does work on API 19 devices.

I've tried to execute the command on real device (nexus 5 with api 23 - marshmallow) and it works with no problem.

Any idea how to overcome the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: do you have to lock it programmatically?!! may be you just have to expant the options menu on the right and then click at power button twice

Comment: yes, I need to perform it through the code (automation test) , but I did try to click on the power button twice , didn't work as well

Comment: have you tried: **adb shell input keyevent 26**

Comment: Yes of course,  it was the second thing I did

Answer (score 0):

try going to settings>security> and set screen lock as swipe

then click the power button twice

Comment: i was just providing another way to lock the device

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer to the issue in [GenyMotion google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/genymotion-users/)

> **If the screen is not useable,** **that might be an opengl issue that is
>   being investigate and should be fix in a next release**.
>
> The screen does not shutdown but keep displaying the desktop although
>   the screen is locked. If you push the power button or send the event
>   82, the lockscreen should be display.